# Flag weight is not getting decrease after flag a post on MSO

Tags: bug, flags, flag-weight

Generally I the post which are "off-topic" for MSO. Since last few days I am noticing that whenever I flag any post as "off-topic" my remaining flag count doesn't get change. Right now I have remaining flag of 47 which. Just about 15 mins I flag two recent post which are off-topic for MSO, [post 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186003/214722),[post 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186006/214722) .

Both the flags turn into "helpful" flag and still I have remaining flag count at 47, it is not decreasing, why so ?